# dragging objects in swing, is MouseMotionListener in the object or in the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, events

There is a question in this textbook I am reading:

"When using Swing, which of the following must be done to allow an object to be dragged in the application window:"

**A.** have a mouseDragged method in the object
**B.** add a MouseListener to the panel
**C.** add a MouseMotionListener to the object
**D.** add a MouseMotionListener to the panel

I think that A is not correct because mouseDragged could be inherited from a parent object. B is wrong since MouseListener isn't used for mouse drags. and since it is the object that we want to drag, I believe that the correct answer is C, but I am not 100% sure that my previous assumptions are correct.

The Java API for MouseMotionListener says that "The listener object created from that class is then registered with a component using the component's addMouseMotionListener method. " so does that mean the object is indeed the one that adds the MouseMotionListener?

Comment: Best way to find the answer: write some code and test it. At least that's what I would do.

Comment: None to the above. Either use the Transfer API or MouseDragGestureRecognizer

Comment: +1 HFOE and Mad. @user2533249 see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359566/how-to-drag-an-image-from-one-panel-to-other/17359895#17359895) example [its variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297481/enable-stringflavor-of-transfersupport-in-java-swing/17299098#17299098). Maybe [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273923/how-can-i-set-the-priority-mouse-listener/14276466#14276466) (relevant parts are at the bottom of the answer where the screen shots start)

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  Must admit I've never understood the DnD API that well. I"ve really only seen it used to move/copy properties from one component to another. If this question is about moving a component to a different location on the same panel, would you still use the Transfer API?

Comment: @camickr Personally, I don't like the transfer API and prefer to use the lower level DnD API. I'd probably be tempted to use the DnD API even for localised transfer only because it would allow me to expand the concept to included dragging components from other parent containers, but a lot would need to come down to what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I don't know the difference between the 2 API's. I've been reading the Swing tutorial on `Drag and Drop and Data Transfer` trying to understand how you might do this. Finally got it to work, but I don't really like the user experience. I think I'll stick with mouse listeners so I can see the component move to its actual position as I drag the mouse rather than waiting until I release the mouse.

Comment: @camickr The transfer API is built ontop of the DnD API and is suppose to make it easier to implement DnD between Swing components, and for what it was designed to do, it does well, but I find it to restrictive. I've want to spend some time with the concepts presented on [this blog](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html?m=1), but haven't had much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer will be

**D.** add a `MouseMotionListener` to the panel.

When you drag something, the coordinates of that object are going to change in the panel in which it is displayed. So, by adding the `MouseMotionListener` to the panel, you can check using if conditions whether the starting point of the drag is within the bounds of your object and write the proper code for handling the drag.

If you add the `MouseMotionListener` in the object itself, it will not be able to track the drag which are going outside the bounds of the object.