# Suggestions on handling the InvalidDnDOperationException exception

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I am creating a Drag and Drog client using java, but keep on running in with the following exception.

```
java.awt.dnd.InvalidDnDOperationException: No drop current
```

This is the code which generates the error

```
list = (List<File>) (info.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor));
```

And the info object is declared as follows

```
TransferHandler.TransferSupport info;
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to solve it.

Comment: Where are you trying to read the transfer data from?  The data may not be available until it is actually dropped

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359566/how-to-drag-an-image-from-one-panel-to-other/17359895#17359895) answer and its [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297481/enable-stringflavor-of-transfersupport-in-java-swing/17299098#17299098) for some examples.

Comment: So I am dragging a file from a directory into the application window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an InvalidDnDOperationException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879171/why-am-i-getting-an-invaliddndoperationexception)